# How to expose multiple interface from a single singleton in RestEasy

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

Let's say we have the following service interfaces:

```
@Path("servicea")
public interface ServiceA {
    @GET void aMethod();
}

@Path("serviceb")
public interface ServiceB {
    @GET void anotherMethod();
}
```

Now, using RestEasy these can easily be exposed as a Rest service using any of the configuration supported. In this case, we have an implementation for `ServiceA` and one for `ServiceB`, which we export via `org.jboss.resteasy.spi.Registry`, like so:

```
Registry registry = (Registry) servletContext.getAttribute("org.jboss.resteasy.spi.Registry");
registry.addSingletonResource(serviceAimpl);
registry.addSingletonResource(serviceBimpl);
```

This works fine. But now, let's say it makes sense to group the two implementation together, under a single class:

```
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceA, ServiceB {
    ...
}

Registry registry = (Registry) servletContext.getAttribute("org.jboss.resteasy.spi.Registry");
registry.addSingletonResource(serviceImpl);
```

I would expect that when I register an object of this class to RestEasy to expose both paths, but it seems like it expose only one of the two. Is there a way to achieve this? Or is this a bug in RestEasy?

Answer (score 1):

Logically the Impl class cannot have two `@Path` annotation at class level and within a class there can be only one `GET` method without the `@Path`. So it is not possible. You can annotate your interface `methods` with `@Path` and that would be honoured.

Comment: Well, the class doesn't have any `@Path` annotation, they're on the interfaces... when resolving `@Path` to use, RestEasy checks the interfaces of a class and stops when it finds one, nothing could prevent it from using all the interfaces that have a `@Path`. For the `GET` issue, it's still the same thing: you can deduce which method to call because of that `@Path` annotation on the interface and the methods are declared in the interface, and using reflection that's all possible to check. Nonetheless, even if the methods are declared with a `@Path` it doesn't work.